# How useful is Facebook Connect Login?

Tags: facebook, authentication, registration

I'm starting to see some Websites offer the option to login via Facebook. I'm curious how useful it is a feature. For example, when someone logs in, does her friend knows on Facebook that she logged in? What if there are more fields that I require than Facebook stores?

Which one would you use from the list of 13 controls?

- http://vatlab.com/facebook-asp-net-libs/facebook-connect-asp-net

It would save me a lot of time to buy the app from them. But I wonder if there is anything else I'm missing out (like a free version elsewhere).

My goal is to make registration/sign up quick and painless so they go through the motion while spreading the word. At the end of the process, the user will receive something (i.e. free e-book).

So it seems that there are 2 points where Facebook can help and perhaps make their friends take notice. Facebook Connect and Facebook invite friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook login integration will let you do just about anything you want.  One complaint people have is that it changes pretty often and that you need to invest a decent amount of time in keeping up with it.  If your goal is to stick with Facebook only and use a lot of the more advanced features then there is value in using it.

However, if you are looking for an easy solution check out http://www.janrain.com/.  There is a free plan and multiple levels of pay for service plans. They also let you connect to more than 1 login provider (OpenID, Twitter, etc).  If you want to learn about the service checkout [This Week in Startups show #73](http://thisweekin.com/thisweekin-startups/this-week-in-startups-73-with-larry-drebes-of-janrain/) for an interview with one of the founders.

Just to be clear, I don't work for or have any vested interested in Janrain.

Comment: JanRain vs VatLab... I noticed JanRain is good for users who want to login with other accounts (besides Facebook).

But they do not seem to have features like Facebook Invite which is crucial to make the Website viral during the sign up process.

Answer (score 3):

These days I will not register with a website if the website has not already proved its **greate** value to me.   However I am more willing to login with Facebook or gmail (openID) as I don't have the pain of yet another password.

So if you website MUST make people log in, then you are likely to get more users with Facebook connect and openId.

However remember that Facebook Connect (and gmail) is blocked on a lot of work networks.

Answer (score 0):

**JanRain vs VatLab**

I noticed JanRain is good for users who want to login with other accounts (besides Facebook).

But they do not seem to have features like **Facebook Invite** which is crucial to make the Website viral during the sign up process.